# Modified binary search with best guess

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm using a pretty straight-forward binary search to return the index of the nearest element (on the lower side):

```
binarySearch = function(a, x) {
    var lo = -1, hi = a.length;
    while (hi - lo > 1) {
        var mid = Math.round((lo + hi)/2);
        if (a[mid] <= x) {
            lo = mid;
        } else {
            hi = mid;
        }
    }
    if (a[lo] == x) hi = lo;
    return lo;
};
```

It works like this:

```
> timestamps = [1, 3, 4, 6, 9];
> binarySearch(timestamps, 5)
2
```

Given the nature of the data (evenly spaced timestamps in a video), I have a pretty good idea beforehand where the nearest timestamp to the current video time will be found:

```
bestGuess = video.currentTime / video.duration * timestamps.length;
```

Is there a way to improve the binary search by starting "close" to the best guess? Something like:

```
betterBinarySearch(timestamps, 5, bestGuess)
```

Before someone calls premature optimization, the arrays have 50-100k timestamps and will be searched as frequently as possible. This is a measured bottleneck.

Comment: It sounds like your best guess is a better fulcrum than the `mid`. Have you tried to change  `var mid = Math.round((lo + hi)/2);` to `var mid = (lo == -1 && hi == a.length) ? bestguess : Math.round((lo + hi)/2);`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search, but I will add one caveat:

Binary search guarantees worst case log n cost because each step divides the search range in two, but this does not hold for interpolation search. One way to guarantee decent worst case behaviour is to alternate between interpolation search steps and binary search steps, or to run a binary search step if the range searched does not decrease as fast as expected.

Comment: Ah, this looks great.